How to work with css when my content div a really wide but the container div didn't grow
I have a problem about content div and container div that the container didn't grow with the content in a full page layout.
Please see the example below:


*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
  height:100vh;
  width:100vw;
  background-color:red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.content{
  width:3000px;
  background-color:lightgreen;
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        content
    </div>
</div>



I do read some blog about how to set up a full page layout. And it work pretty fine if the screen is big enough, but as responsive layout it's not well on the device.
I can wrap the words for a paragraph, but if I'm showing a table or some element with min-width which is bigger than the device's vw.
The element will grow horizontially but the container div doesn't, so the element penetrate the container.
What I want is the container and content grow together so I cant view them with horizontial scroll without any penetration.
Hwo can I do that?

Setting fixed heights/widths is almost never a good choice if your goal is to create a responsive layout. You can always use some CSS Layout like flexbox or grid.

@lzanagi Would you show me a example? I tried to make it with flexbox and the result is almost, the container wont' grow wider than 100vw.
